# Doctrine ORM: prevent converting date to DateTime object instead of string

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine orm to get date from DB.

```php
$r = $queryBuilder
            ->select('create_date')
            ->addOrderBy('name')
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->setHydrationMode(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
            ->getArrayResult();
```

It returns an array

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [create_date] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 1985-01-15 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )
        )
)
```

But I don't want to get DateTime Object. I want to get a single string `1985-01-15`. Is there a way to do that without casting column in the select?
The same issue is not reproducible in the doctrine DBAL

Comment: Conversion between the database and PHP types depends on your [field mappings](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/basic-mapping.html). If you've specified a date type (date, datetime, etc) then you'll always get a DateTime object back from the ORM. You can either change the type or it might make more sense to just convert back to YYYY-MM-DD format in your presentation layer instead.